# use extern structure variable defined in a library, config with cmake

Tags: c, cmake

main.c

```
#include "test.h"
extern struct test_struct my_test_str; // defined in my_test_lib.a 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   return 0;
}
```

here is the my_test_my library file of test.h and test.c
compiled as my_test_lib.a

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_MY
#define TEST_MY
struct test_struct {
  double d1;
  double d2;
  double d3;
};
void ddd(void);
#endif
```

test.c

```
struct test_struct my_test_str;
void ddd(void) {
  int a = 0;
  int c = 1;
  c = a + c;
}
```

write CMakeLists.txt , use cmake to generated Makefile

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(Tutorial)

add_library(my_test_my test.c)
add_executable(Tutorial main.c)
target_link_libraries (Tutorial my_test_my)
```

after generate Makefiles in a out directory, execute the make

```
192:out jerryw$ make
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/my_test_my.dir/test.c.o
[ 50%] Linking C static library libmy_test_my.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libmy_test_my.a(test.c.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libmy_test_my.a(test.c.o) has no symbols
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: warning for library: libmy_test_my.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
[ 50%] Built target my_test_my
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/Tutorial.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable Tutorial
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ddd", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_my_test_str", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [Tutorial] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Tutorial.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

why this happened ?

Comment: **All** declarations should always go into the header of the module/library which also defines it. `#include` the header in **every** compilation unit which requires any of its declarations.

Comment: Somehow, you've created a `test.c.o` file which you're trying to load into a library, but `test.c.o` contains no symbols according to the error message.  The file name for the object file would conventionally be `test.o` and not `test.c.o` — you might need to track that down.  And the link fails because the symbols that should be in the library aren't, so the linker fails to find them.

Comment: very strange ? if i call the ddd function in main, the symbol  test_struct and ddd can be linked. if i don't call the ddd function in main program, make will report error for  _test_struct symbol is not undefined.   does it really rule should call the library function first then can link to the external struct defined in that library?

Comment: yes, i clear the cmake cache.  use the nm to check. if call the ddd function first every this is fine. but if don't call ddd function, then the external struct would not be linked.

Comment: nm libmy_test_my.a 

libmy_test_my.a(test.c.o):
0000000000000000 T _ddd
0000000000000018 C _my_test_str

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of all problems, but you are missing `#include "test.h"` at the beginning of test.c . You are getting an error about `ddd` which you are not even calling from `main`: I strongly suggest you restart from a clean (empty) build directory. In the main function, add some operations on the struct, and a call to `ddd()`

Comment: both the file `test.c` and the file `main.c` need to have the statement: `#include "test.h"` added